# Aligning the headnumbercontent with headtextcontent in headalternative

Tags: context

I'm working on a master ConTeXt template to typeset multiple books, which means I needed to account for chapters that may or may not have a subtitle, epigraph, etc. I found the exact solution I was looking for in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247147/table-of-contents-for-poetry-collection-context/248096#248096), except for one problem...

When I start adding extra lines, i.e. typesetting the subtitle below the title, the chapter number is aligned with the subtitle line rather than staying with the title line.

*Note:* I used `alternative=margin` in `\setuphead` before switching to this solution. To retain that design with the new renderingsetup, I added `\inleftmargin{}` to Aditya's solution. Not sure if it's relevant but I thought I'd point it out, just in case.

***Edit:*** Here's the minimal, compilable example...

```
\setuphead [chapter][alternative=newchapterhead]

\defineheadalternative
  [newchapterhead]
  [renderingsetup=newchapterhead]

\startsetups newchapterhead
    \vbox {
    \inleftmargin{\headnumbercontent}\space\headtextcontent
    \doifsomething{\structureuservariable{subtitle}}
      {\blank[small]\structureuservariable{subtitle}}}
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startchapter[title={My Chapter Title}][subtitle={My Chapter Subtitle}]
\input knuth
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Compiles to:
[image: Minimal Example Result]

Comment: Please make a minmal and complete (compilable) example.

Comment: Sorry @Thomas, see edit. I thought I'd made it minimal enough the first time, until I tried to create a compilable version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mmh, I would use ConTeXt's framed mechanism instead of a vbox, and `\margindata`. Here's my suggestion:

```
\definemargindata [chapterhead] [left] 

\setuphead [chapter][alternative=newchapterhead]

\defineheadalternative
  [newchapterhead]
  [renderingsetup=newchapterhead]

\startsetups newchapterhead
    \framed[align=right,frame=off]{\chapterhead{\headnumbercontent}\headtextcontent
    \doifsomething{\structureuservariable{subtitle}}
      {\blank[small]\structureuservariable{subtitle}}}
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startchapter[title={My Chapter Title}][subtitle={My Chapter Subtitle}]
  \input knuth
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Which does, I believe, what you want:
[image]

Btw, nice example!

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much @Thomas! I certainly hadn't used, and not sure I'd even _seen_ `\definemargindata` before, so I never would have gotten there on my own. Much obliged!

Comment: `margindata` is a pretty new mechanism and has, as far as I know, more configurable options than the older `inmargin`. There isn't much documentation around, but the source in `typo-mar.mkiv` is pretty readable (well, at least the interesting parts...).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `\dontleavehmode` in your definition.  The `\space` is unnecessary and in this answer even harmful.

```
\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [alternative=newchapterhead]

\defineheadalternative
  [newchapterhead]
  [renderingsetup=newchapterhead]

\startsetups newchapterhead
    \vbox{%
      \dontleavehmode
      \inleftmargin{\headnumbercontent}
      \headtextcontent
      \doifsomething{\structureuservariable{subtitle}}
        {\blank[small]\structureuservariable{subtitle}}}
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startchapter[title={My Chapter Title}][subtitle={My Chapter Subtitle}]
  \input knuth
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Henri - I realized after I posted that the unnecessary `\space` was still in the example. It was leftover from testing this setup _without_ the number being in the margin.