# How to produce a table of contents for a journal giving both article title and author name?

Tags: context

I edit a small club journal which prints articles submitted by the members. Currently I'm using MS Word but want to change to ConTeXt. My desire is to have one file per article, with a master 'issue' file containing \input commands, one for each article.

I've created a custom command to standardise the appearance of the article title and author:

```
\JournalArticle{The Title of the Article}{Author Name}
```

and now I'd like to extend this to create a table of contents automatically. Currently I do the ToC by hand, producing a table similar to:

```
\starttable[|l|l|r]
\HL
\NC \bf Title \NC \bf Author \NC \bf Page \NC \FR
\HL
\NC The Title of the Article \NC John Doe      \NC 1 \NC\NR
\NC Second Article           \NC Jack Daniels  \NC 2 \NC\NR
\NC Third Article            \NC John Doe      \NC 2 \NC\LR
\HL
\stoptable
```

My problem is that I can't work out how to do this automatically.

I've looked at \defineregister et al but can't see how to store two values (title and name).

Alternatively I could use a buffer (since I don't need to sort the titles, just list them in the order they appear) but I can't see how to append to a buffer each time a new \JournalArticle is encountered.

Can someone point me to where this problem has been solved before, or suggest a solution please?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373136/11604

Comment: That link is for a LaTeX solution. I was hoping for ConTeXt.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution in this previous question which has a nice answer.

[Table of Contents for a poetry collection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247147/table-of-contents-for-poetry-collection-context?rq=1)